# change option color in select2 plugin

Tags: jquery-select2

I am using the select2 plugin and I like to change the text color on some options like this:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single">
    <option>item 1</option>
    <option style="color:red">item 2</option>
    <option>item 3</option>
    <option style="color:red">item 4</option>
</select>
```

But when I execute the page, the `style` not works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit the appearance of your options you need to use the [templating options of the select2](https://select2.org/selections#templating)

You will need to do something like this:

```
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
   templateSelection: function(data) {
       return $('<span style="color:red">' + data.text +'<span>');
   }
});
```

Be aware that if you only want some options to be red you will need to do the checks inside the function.

Hope this helps.